# Android Facebook key hash -- "remote_app_id does not match stored id"

Tags: java, android, facebook, hash, app-id

I am trying to implement Facebook log in and then allow the user to post status updates and share details to Facebook through the app.  I (think) the user is not successfully able to log into Facebook.  Below is the process the user goes through:

- User clicks Login button
- User logs in successfully
- Below window appears to user

[image: status pic]

- When the user hits the `Share` button, this error message appears:  `(#404) remote_app_id does not match stored id`

I have gotten the Key Hashes for my debug keystore and release keystore using the below 2 command lines.

Debug Keystore

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\lyonsmg\.android\debug.keystore | C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.exe sha1 -binary | C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.exe base64
```

Release Keystore

```
keytool -exportcert -alias C:\Users\lyonsmg\matt\_keystores_and_passwords\BibleTriviaLite_keystore -keystore C:\Users\lyonsmg\matt\_keystores_and_passwords\BibleTriviaLite_keystore | C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.exe sha1 -binary | C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.exe
```

I used `android` as the password for the debug keystore and my private password for the release keystore.  I placed both of the resulting key hashes in Developers Settings on Facebook and also in Facebook App Dashboard.  Its the 2 places that the Facebook Android SDK docs tell me to put it.

I have my app_id that is found in the Facebook App Dashboard in my `Android Manifest`.  Below is my Android Manifest and you can see the 2 spots where my app_id is found.  You can find it in the code as `@string/app_id`.

Android Manifest

```
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="matt.lyons.bibletrivia.lite"
    android:versionCode="13"
    android:versionName="2.1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_blue_bg"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".About"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".Categories"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".Question"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".Quiz"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".QuestionView"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".Results"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".Highscores"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".DatabaseHelper"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".ComingSoon"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".MainMenu"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".MyApplication"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".Levels"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".GameType"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <meta-data android:value="@string/app_id" android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"/>
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"></activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
</manifest>
```

Sorry I wrote so much but I was just trying to cover all my bases and be thorough!  My question is, what am I doing wrong?  Why is it telling me that my "remote_app_id" does not match my "stored id"?

Comment: I stuck on the same issue... Please let me know if you solve it ! :)

Comment: @AdrienCerdan, I never fixed this.  I just had to give up and take it out for the time being.

Comment: i fixed it !! For release mode, your -alias isn't a path, but the "Key Name" that you see when you export your signed application with eclipse, that is the name of your alias !!

Answer (score 1):

You're using the same `value="@string/app_id"` for both `com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID` and `com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId`.

Your Facebook app ID can't possibly be the same as your Google app ID. You need to get the Facebook app ID from the Facebook App Dashboard.

Comment: Same error message appears after I made the fix about the 2 app_ids you pointed out.  And thanks for the fix!  I'm sure that fixed a future bug that I would have had.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, the hash code that i generated through openssl was wrong i then used this function and it help. Hope it help you all too.

```
private void printKeyHash() {
    // Add code to print out the key hash
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("YOUR PACKAGE NAME", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("KeyHash:", e.toString());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.e("KeyHash:", e.toString());
    }
}
```

Use the hash code that is printed in logs and enjoy. Happy Coding :)